# How to write multiple filters and maps in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void applyServiceDetails(Service svc, Response resp) {
        if (resp.getService().getExtensionAttributes() != null) {
            if (resp.getService().getExtensionAttributes().getItem() != null) {
                for (Attribute attrib : resp.getService().getExtensionAttributes().getItem()) {
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_ETHERNET_SERVICE_TYPE.equals(attrib.getName())) { svc.setServiceType(attrib.getValue()); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_BANDWIDTH_TYPE.equals(attrib.getName()))        { svc.setBandwidthType(getBandwidthType(attrib.getValue())); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_CFS_ID.equals(attrib.getName()))                { svc.setCfsId(attrib.getValue()); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_RFS_ID.equals(attrib.getName()))                { svc.setRfsId(attrib.getValue()); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID.equals(attrib.getName()))   { svc.setAccountNumber(attrib.getValue()); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NAME.equals(attrib.getName())) { svc.setAccountName(attrib.getValue()); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_PIID.equals(attrib.getName()))                  { svc.setPiid(attrib.getValue());
                                                                                                   String[] split = StringUtils.split(attrib.getValue(), "_");
                                                                                                   svc.setOrderId((split.length > 1) ? split[1] : attrib.getValue());
                    }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_BANDWIDTH_SPEED.equals(attrib.getName()))       { svc.setBandwidthSpeed(attrib.getValue()); }
                    if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID.equals(attrib.getName()))     { svc.setOrderNumber(attrib.getValue()); }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with Streams? To me it looks like you want to use switch-case

Comment: Looking for instead of IF conditions can we make it streams().filter().map() function.

Comment: `Stream.map` is for transforming data. But you're not transforming data. You're just executing methods. Your code basically looks fine, but I would use `if ... else if ... else if` or `switch case` (if your `Contants...` are `enum` or `String`) to avoid unnecessary computations, because: When the first `if` statement is `true`, then all the other `if` statements can be skipped and there's no need to check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions how you can write your code in some different styles:

Using `if ... else if` inside the `for` loop:

```java
for(...) {
  if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_ETHERNET_SERVICE_TYPE.equals(attrib.getName())) {
    svc.setServiceType(attrib.getValue());
  } else if (Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_BANDWIDTH_TYPE.equals(attrib.getName())) {
    svc.setBandwidthType(getBandwidthType(attrib.getValue()));
  } else if (...) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Using `switch case` inside the `for` loop:

```java
for(...) {
  switch(attrib.getName()) {
  case Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_ETHERNET_SERVICE_TYPE:
    svc.setServiceType(attrib.getValue());
    break;
  case Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_BANDWIDTH_TYPE:
    svc.setBandwidthType(getBandwidthType(attrib.getValue()));
    break;
  case ...:
    ...
    break;
  }
}
```

**Don't forget to `break` after each `case`!**

Using `Optional` for the first two conditions:

```java
public void applyServiceDetails(Service svc, Response resp) {
  Optional.ofNullable(resp.getService().getExtensionAttributes())
    .map(attrs -> attrs.getItem())
    .ifPresent(item -> {
      for(Attribute attrib : item) { 
        // ...
      }
    });
}
```

Using `forEach` instead of `for` loop:

```java
resp.getService().getExtensionAttributes().getItem().forEach(attrib -> {
  if (...) {
    ...
  } else if (...) {
    ...
  } else if (...) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Or a combination of the above:

```java
public void applyServiceDetails(Service svc, Response resp) {
  Optional.ofNullable(resp.getService().getExtensionAttributes())
    .map(attrs -> attrs.getItem())
    .stream()
    .flatMap(item -> item.stream())
    .forEach(attrib -> {
      switch(attrib.getName()) {
      case Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_ETHERNET_SERVICE_TYPE:
        svc.setServiceType(attrib.getValue());
        break;
      case Constants.ATTRIB_SVC_BANDWIDTH_TYPE:
        svc.setBandwidthType(getBandwidthType(attrib.getValue()));
        break;
      case ...:
        ...
        break;
      }
    });
}
```